# How do you pass multiple functions as constrainment parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, methods, delegates

This might be a badly worded question for what I'm trying to learn so I'll explain what I am trying to do. I have the following list being created using the following expression:

```
var showIndexes = from item in lItems
                               where WildcardString.IsMatch(item.RecordId.ToString(), filter) ||
                                     WildcardString.IsMatch(item.Tokens.ToString(), filter) ||
                                     WildcardString.IsMatch(string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.OwnerID.SystemName, item.OwnerID.Port.ToString()), filter) ||
                                     WildcardString.IsMatch(item.ChildID.UserName, filter) ||
                                     WildcardString.IsMatch(item.TypeOfLicense.ToString(), filter) ||
                                     WildcardString.IsMatch(item.ExpiryTime.DateTime.ToLocalTime().ToString(), filter)
                               select item.RecordId.ToString();
```

I want to put this expression into a function, and pass in constrainments used in the "where" in as a single parameter. How do I achieve this? I've seen similar functionality using the bitwise OR when working with file attributes (when you select different attribute enums) so I believe it should be possible to write my own function which takes a group of delegates as the "where" rule.

If it is relevant, WildcardString.IsMatch(string, string) is a boolean function. Also, I have three different functions performing the exact same thing but on different lists, which is why I'd like to learn how to do reduce this to a single function, and just pass the list and the selection rules in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply define a predicate: a function that takes an `item` and returns a boolean.

Assuming that `item` is of type `Record` and that `filter` is in scope:

```
Func<Record, bool> predicate = r =>
    WildCardString.IsMatch(r.RecordId.ToString(), filter) ||
    WildCardString.IsMatch(...);
```

You can then treat `predicate` as a first-class value (store it, pass it as a parameter, etc) and filter any `IEnumerable<Record>` with

```
var filtered = enumerable.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: @BasedAsFunk: You should devote some time to understanding lambdas and how they capture their environment (in this example the environment is `filter`) to ensure there are no surprises. A very powerful tool, but as always you need to take care how you are using it.

Comment: I've used them a bit in the past but I don't really know anything about them. It's on my TODO list of things to pick up on

Answer (score 2):

Well just refactor the where part into a function:

```
public bool MyIsMatch(MyType item, String filter)
{
    return
    WildcardString.IsMatch(item.RecordId.ToString(), filter) ||
    WildcardString.IsMatch(item.Tokens.ToString(), filter) ||
    WildcardString.IsMatch(string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.OwnerID.SystemName, item.OwnerID.Port.ToString()), filter) ||
    WildcardString.IsMatch(item.ChildID.UserName, filter) ||
    WildcardString.IsMatch(item.TypeOfLicense.ToString(), filter) ||
    WildcardString.IsMatch(item.ExpiryTime.DateTime.ToLocalTime().ToString(), filter);
}
```

And then call it:

```
var showIndexes = from item in lItems where MyIsMatch(item, filter) select item.ToString();
```

Comment: The only reason this doesn't work for me is because now I'll need 3 MyIsMatch functions. I want to create one function and create the constrainment parameters on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a version of Is.Match that takes a list of valid values

```
public static bool IsMatch(IEnumerable<object> values, filter) {
    return values.All(v => IsMatch(v.ToString(),filter))
}
```

in your case you'd use it like this

```
var values = new object[]{
                    item.RecordId,
                    item.Tokens,
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", item.OwnerID.SystemName, item.OwnerID.Port),
                    item.ChildID.UserName
                    item.TypeOfLicense
                    item.ExpiryTime.DateTime};

var showIndexes = from item in lItems
                  where WildcardString.IsMatch(values,filter)
                           select item.RecordId.ToString();
```

I've chose to use `IEnumerable<object>` instead of `IEnumerable<string>` to remove the `.ToString()` from each item this however does come with a sleight cost since you'll be boxing and unboxing any ValueTyped values. If it's on an identified performance critical path you should use `IEnumerable<string>` instead

Comment: I'm not really well versed in lambda expressions, but VS is whining about v.ToString in your IsMatch function

Comment: @BasedAsFunk it was whinning because of a typo which is now fixed :)

Comment: Haha, I thought that's what you had meant to use, but I don't know enough on the subject to know if you made a different mistake haha

Comment: @BasedAsFunk you can read a lambda pretty much as declaring a function. Everything that comes before => is parameter names (you usually do not have to type them but you can) every thing that comes after => is the method body if it's one expression you can omit { and } and return if it's more than one expression/statement you will have to use {} around the body as you usually do and explicitly return (if you need to return a value as in this case)